# Sum function in Redshift ignoring decimal values

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, sum, amazon-redshift

I have a column named `myh`. It has decimal values like: `65.20`, `56.49`

When I tried to sum up in Redshift using `sum()`, it is showing the result as `121` and it is ignoring the decimal values.

Is there any solution to get decimals also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Round` function for addition of values. Also you can use `CAST`

```
DECLARE @A DECIMAL(13,5)
DECLARE @B DECIMAL(13,5)
SET @A = 65.20
SET @B = 56.49

SELECT CAST(@A+@B AS decimal)

SELECT ROUND(SUM(@A+@B),2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to `Cast` it?

Example:

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(myh as decimal(10,2)))
```